# Hovering on/off in jquery trouble

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to figure out how only activate my hover state when the mouse is over a certain div, resetting when the mouse leaves that div. I have 2 divs side by side, `.purple` and `.orange`, each has a div. spacer on either side, my goal is to have `.orange` slide over `.purple` while hovering `.spacer`, and then hide again when `.spacer` is no longer hovered. everything works bueatifully when entering hover, but i cant make it stop when the mouse leaves `.spacer`.

heres my code so far.

```
 $('.purple .spacer').hover(function() {
    zindex = zindex + 1;

    $('.orange').css('left', '100vw');
    $('.orange').css('z-index', zindex);
    $('.orange').animate({'left': '90vw'}, 1000);`
```

Comment: Where is your markup?

Comment: Could you provide the associated HTML or a JSfiddle so we can see what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.hover()`, you need two functions inside it; One for `mouseenter`, and one for `mouseleave`. Like so:

```js
$(".hover").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','green');
  }
);
```

```css
.hover {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">Hover</div>
```

If you don't do that, it will stay red even after `mouseleave`, like so:

```js
$(".hover").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
  }
);
```

```css
.hover {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">Hover</div>
```